# Python KNN Impute using custom weights

Tags: python, knn

Need to do a KNN Impute in python using custom weights. Sklearn Documentation states I can use "Callable function", but does not give any clear guidance.
Can someone kindly shed some light please?

[Random dataset I generated, to simulate my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41vVy.png)

I need to impute the NaNs in the **Loan ** column.

Quite new to Python and thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

From the [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html), the "weights" keyword accepts a callable in the form of:

> callable : a user-defined function which accepts an array of distances, and returns an array of the same shape containing the weights.

So the function has an `input_arr` as input and `output_arr` of the same length as output. If you want to use the column `"Weight_var"` from the DataFrame `df` as weights, your function would look like this:

```
def impute_fn(input_arr):
    weight_arr = df["Weight_var"] # use your custom weights
    assert len(input_arr) == len(output_arr) # lengths have to match, as described in the documentation
    return weight_arr
```

In this case, you are not using the `input_arr` of the impute_fn (because you will use your own predetermined weights).

In the KNNImputer, remember to pass the callable, and not the function call:

```
sklearn.impute.KNNImputer(
    missing_values=YOUR_ARRAY, 
    weights=impute_fn # NO ()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply --

I tried your suggestion as follows --

'knnimp = KNNImputer(n_neighbours = 3, weights = 'distance', metric = impute_fn)'  --

this gives a TypeError : impute_fn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'missing_values' --

If I use () to indicate impute_fn is a function, again get an error --

'knnimp = KNNImputer(n_neighbours = 3, weights = 'distance', metric = impute_fn())' --

this gives a TypeError : impute_fn() missing 1 required positional argument:  'argument_name'' --

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: are you trying to fill the weights with the "weights" keyword or change the metric with the "metric" keyword? from you question I supposed the weights are to be changed.

Comment: Columns in my df are like: ['X_var1', 'X_var2', 'X_var3', 'Weight_var','Y_var'] --     
I want it to use 'Weight_var' column values as weights in the imputer -- 
    --> def impute_fn(input_var):
    -->         # I am not sure what this input_var is going to be!!!
    -->     # how do I relate the output_var to input_var, based on Weight_var in my df?
    -->      return output_var
 -- 
my imputer definition line would look like: --

    imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors = 2, weights = impute_fn, metric = 'nan_euclidean') -- Thanks again

Comment: I updated my answer to match your question. I hope this helps. PS: if you just want to fill NaN values, it might be worth looking into pandas.fillna https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: Inside the impute_fn() I added a line to print the input_arr as a check. -- I noticed that, when the "n_neighbors = K" and 'no of NANs in the column that needs to be imputed  = M',  input_arr is a matrix of size "K * M"  generated somehow.  --
I wonder how input_arr get generated. -- 
My weigh_arr is a column of values, hence it is never going to be equal to the size of input_arr, hence always get an AssertionError. --
In the inpute_fn() above, you had a line  "assert len(input_arr) == len(output_arr)". I guess this had a typo as we never defined a output_arr anywhere. -- Thanks